# Example tag in Specflow

Tags: specflow

How to Use the Example Tag in Specflow ? What is that mean in the gherkin Syntax . Any example or blog redirection will help, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about directly from the [github examples](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow-Examples/blob/master/ASP.NET-MVC/BookShop/BookShop.AcceptanceTests/US01_BookSearch.feature)?

Basically, this usually goes with a `Scenario Outline`, which is just a way of running the same scenario with different input/output data without having to retype the entire scenario. Usually, I have seen this as `Scenarios`, but it appears the `Examples` will work also.

From the example:

The following two scenarios:

```
Scenario: Title should be matched
    When I perform a simple search on 'Domain'
    Then the book list should exactly contain book 'Domain Driven Design'

Scenario: Space should be treated as multiple OR search
    When I perform a simple search on 'Windows Communication'
    Then the book list should exactly contain books 'Inside Windows SharePoint Services', 'Bridging the Communication Gap'
```

Are the same as this one Scenario Outline

```
@alternative_syntax
Scenario Outline: Simple search (scenario outline syntax)
    When I perform a simple search on '<search phrase>'
    Then the book list should exactly contain books <books>

    Examples:
        |search phrase          |books                                                                  |
        |Domain                 |'Domain Driven Design'                                                 |
        |Windows Communication  |'Inside Windows SharePoint Services', 'Bridging the Communication Gap' |
```